# When I deploy my java app to IBM Bluemix using Liberty, the buildpack renames it to myapp.war. How to retain my original war file name?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, buildpack

I have created a sample java application and packaged it JavaHelloWorldApp.war.

I deploy it to IBM Bluemix using the command cf push MyHelloWorldApp -p JavaHelloWorldApp.war

After deploy, when I navigate to Runtime file of my deployed application I see that the war file name is shown as myapp.war. See the image in the link below

[image: Image showing generated war file with default name]

I would like to retain my original war file name. As I want to encode my app version details in the war file name and would like the retain it for the reference. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push a liberty server package zip instead of the war

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/01/modify-liberty-server-xml-configurations-ibm-bluemix/

Comment: Nice article. I tried the same without installing liberty profile. I gave the steps  below.

Answer (score 0):

Without Liberty profile :

I could retain the war file name by deploying the JavaHelloWorldApp.war. I have listed the steps below:-

1. Follow the step provided at Bluemix documentation   https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/optionsForPushing.html

   Go to section Server Directory -> then follow steps for, If a Liberty profile is not installed on your workstation, you can use the following steps to create a server directory with your application...
2. Follow all the steps listed there.
3. Finally the defaultServer directory structure should look like this.

   [image]

   My server.xml looks like as given below

   ```
    <server>
       <featureManager>
           <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
       </featureManager>

       <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                 host="*"
                 httpPort="${port}">
           <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>
       </httpEndpoint>

       <application name="JavaHelloWorldApp" context-  
        root="/JavaHelloWorldApp" location="JavaHelloWorldApp.war"     
        type="war"/>
    </server>
   ```
4. Now to deploy defaultServer run command: 
   cf push  -p defaultServer
5. The java application will deploy into Bluemix and the war file name
   will be named JavaHelloWorldApp.war, same as the application war file
   name.Snapshot below :-

   [image: Custom War file name]